# Fetching only rows that match all entries in a joined table (SQL)

Tags: sql, join

I have the following five tables:

- ISP
- Product
- Connection
- AddOn
- AddOn/Product (pivot table for many-to-many relationship).

Each Product is linked to an ISP, each Connection is listed to a Product. Each product can have a number of add-ons, through the use of the pivot table (which simply has 2 fields, one for the product ID and one for the AddOn ID).

The result I am interested in is each connection with the addons listed (I am making use of MySQL's GROUP_CONCAT for this, to make a comma-separated list of the addon's *name* field). This works fine as is, the query looks something like this:

```
SELECT i.name AS ispname, i.img_link, c.download, c.upload, c.monthly_price, c.link, 
GROUP_CONCAT(a.name) AS addons, SUM(pa.monthly_fee) AS addon_price
FROM isp i JOIN product p ON i.id = p.isp_id
JOIN `connection` c ON p.id = c.product_id LEFT JOIN product_addon pa ON pa.product_id = p.id AND pa.forced = 0
LEFT JOIN addon a ON pa.addon_id = a.id GROUP BY c.id
```

I am using LEFT JOINS as it is possible for products to have no addons at all.

My problem is that it is possible to select some addons that listed connections MUST have, presented as a list of addon IDs, like (1,14,237). If I put it in as an additional condition in the JOIN statements (*AND pa.addon_id IN (...)*), it will return all connections that have just one of the listed addons, but not necessarily all of them.

Is there some way to return all connections that as a **minimum** have all the addons (they can have additional as well) via SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
GROUP BY set-of-column
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN ISNULL(pa.addon_id, 0) IN (1,14,237) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add to the WHERE clause:

```
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM addon a2
                WHERE  a2.addon_id IN (1,14,237)
                AND NOT EXISTS
                ( SELECT NULL
                  FROM   product_addon pa2
                  WHERE  pa2.addon_id = a2.addon_id
                  AND    pa2.product_id = p.product_id
                )
               )
```

Or equivalently:

```
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM addon a2
                LEFT JOIN product_addon pa2
                  ON pa2.addon_id = a2.addon_id
                 AND pa2.product_id = p.product_id
                WHERE a2.addon_id IN (1,14,237)
                AND   pa2.product_id IS NULL
                )
               )
```