# Filtering from join-table

Tags: sql, mysql, join, filtering

I'm having some trouble with a tricky SQL-query.

In my MySQL database there is the tables topics, tags and tags_topics to join them.
I want to fetch topics that share the same specified tags. For example, let's say i have 3 tags with ids 1, 2 and 3, i want to fetch all topics that have tag 1, 2 and 3 associated to them. The topics can have other tags, but must have all of the specified tags.

Help me think plz xD

EDIT: Found a solution using GROUP BY in this question: [Fetching only rows that match all entries in a joined table (SQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333750/fetching-only-rows-that-match-all-entries-in-a-joined-table-sql)
If anyone have a more elegant solution, please post :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**`JOIN` solution:**

```
SELECT t.*
FROM topics t
 JOIN tags_topics t1 ON (t.id = t1.topicId AND t1.tagId = 1)
 JOIN tags_topics t2 ON (t.id = t2.topicId AND t2.tagId = 2)
 JOIN tags_topics t3 ON (t.id = t3.topicId AND t3.tagId = 3)
```

**`GROUP BY` solution:**

Note that you need to list all `t.*` columns in the `GROUP BY` clause, unless you use MySQL or SQLite.

```
SELECT t.*
FROM topics t JOIN tags_topics tt 
  ON (t.id = tt.topicId AND tt.tagId IN (1,2,3))
GROUP BY t.id, ...
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3;
```

**Subquery solution:**

```
SELECT t.*
FROM topics t
WHERE t.id = ANY (SELECT topicId FROM tags_topics tt WHERE tt.tagId = 1)
  AND t.id = ANY (SELECT topicId FROM tags_topics tt WHERE tt.tagId = 2)
  AND t.id = ANY (SELECT topicId FROM tags_topics tt WHERE tt.tagId = 3);
```

**Modified `GROUP BY` solution:**

Simplifies `GROUP BY` clause by isolating search in a subquery.

```
SELECT t.*
FROM topics t
WHERE t.id IN (
  SELECT tt.topicId FROM tags_topics tt 
  WHERE tt.tagId IN (1,2,3))
  GROUP BY tt.id HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
);
```

Comment: COUNT(*) should be > 2, because topics can also have other tags. Thanks for all suggestions though! Edit that, and i'll set it as the right answer ;)

Comment: @finpingvin - the other tags are not considered in the statement. The COUNT(*) = 3 will be correct, so long as there are no duplicates in the junction table

Comment: Yes, I'm assuming tags_topics has a primary key over {topicId, tagId}.  Btw, I edited the fourth solution to avoid a join inside the subquery, after reading @Russ Cam's solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 
    topic_id
FROM
    tags_topics
WHERE
    tag_id IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY
    topic_id
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 2  /* or use COUNT(*) = 3 if you know that there cannot be duplicates in the junction table */
```

Comment: +1 for avoiding the join, by using only the intersection table.  This provides the relevant topic_id values, but not the full topic entity.