# How to do this query in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql-match-all

I have 3 tables, message, subject and `message_subject_rel`. The idea is to have messages that can relate to a lot of subjects and then do a cross subject search.

Lets say I have a message:

```
Id: 1, Message: This is a message
```

2 subjects:

```
Id:1, Subject: Math
Id:2, Subject: Science
```

And there's 2 `message_subject_rel` entries that go:

```
Id: 1, message_id: 1, subject_id: 1
Id: 2, message_id: 1, subject_id: 2
```

If i wanted to search the messages that are related with math, I would do a simple join with the 3 tables and the where clause would be subject = "Math"

But what I don't know how to do, is search for the messages that are related with math AND Science.
If i do a simple join i get tables with something like:

```
id  message     user_id     created_at  ip  id  message_id  subject_id  id  subject
```

And if I do a `where subject = "Math" and subject = "Science"` i wont get any results because each message will only have 1 subject related in each row, but duplicated rows for messages with more than 1 subject.

So, what do you recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basically the same question as [Filtering from join-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648308/filtering-from-join-table/)

I'll adapt my answer from that question.

**JOIN solution:**

```
SELECT m.*
FROM messages m
 JOIN message_subject_rel ms1 ON (m.id = ms1.message_id)
 JOIN subjects s1 ON (ms1.subject_id = s1.id AND s1.subject = 'Math')
 JOIN message_subject_rel ms2 ON (m.id = ms1.message_id)
 JOIN subjects s2 ON (ms2.subject_id = s2.id AND s2.subject = 'Science');
```

**GROUP BY solution:**

Note that you need to list all m.* columns in the `GROUP BY` clause, unless you use MySQL.

```
SELECT m.*
FROM messages m 
 JOIN message_subject_rel ms ON (m.id = ms.message_id)
 JOIN subjects s ON (ms.subject_id = s.id)
WHERE s.subject IN ('Math', 'Science'))
GROUP BY m.id, ...
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

**Subquery solution:**

```
SELECT m.*
FROM messages m
WHERE m.id = ANY (SELECT message_id 
                  FROM message_subject_rel ms JOIN subjects s 
                    ON (ms.subject_id = s.id) 
                  WHERE s.subject = 'Math')
  AND m.id = ANY (SELECT message_id 
                  FROM message_subject_rel ms JOIN subjects s 
                    ON (ms.subject_id = s.id) 
                  WHERE s.subject = 'Science');
```

**Modified GROUP BY solution:**

Simplifies GROUP BY clause by isolating search in a subquery.

```
SELECT m.*
FROM messages m
WHERE m.id IN (
  SELECT ms.message_id FROM message_subject_rel ms JOIN subjects s
    ON (ms.subject_id = s.id)
  WHERE s.subject IN ('Math', 'Science'))
  GROUP BY ms.message_id HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
);
```

PS: There's no reason your `message_subject_rel` table needs an `ID` column.

Answer (score 0):

Do an inner select in your where clause.

SELECT  FROM [tables and joins] WHERE subject = "Math" AND message_id IN (SELECT message_id FROM [tables and joins] WHERE subject = "Science")

Comment: That could work, but there will be messages with a lot of subject and for that i would like to avoid it, but lets see what happen