# How to select data from database given an include ALL restriction?

Tags: sql

I am currently learning how to program in SQL. I have a `table1` with `firstname`, `lastname` and `roomname`.
And I have another `table2` that has all the `roomnames`.

I was wondering how to select `firstname` and `lastname` from those people who have been in ALL of the rooms. Do I need a `GROUP BY`?

Comment: What dialect of SQL are you working with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For TransactSQL, if you know that every row in your first table is distinct, then this would work:

```
SELECT
   firstname,
   lastname
FROM
   table1
GROUP BY
   firstname,
   lastname
HAVING
   COUNT(DISTINCT RoomName) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2)
```

This should be pretty efficient, but not too flexible, in case you wanted to ignore certain rooms.

Comment: What if names are repeated in table1?

Comment: It's fine if names are repeated, as long as they would always have a different room attached. That is, the combination of firstname, lastname and roomname is unique for every row.

Comment: what if they do have the same room attached? this is basically the problem I am facing right now...

Comment: I've changed my answer slightly. It should now handle this. *But* once you are getting entirely duplicate rows, you are in a bad place. Either your tables are structured poorly, or your approach to the problem is wrong (i.e. you are asking the wrong question).

Answer (score 1):

Group by is a command in order to group your results

As I can see you have duplicates in table1:
Let's say:

```
**table1:**
firstname lastname roomname
Theodore  Hello    roomA
Mike      World    roomA
Theodore  Hello    roomB
Theodore  Hello    roomC
NickThe   Greek    roomC

And **table2:**
roomname
roomA
roomB
roomC
```

As you can see Theodore is the one that had passed from all rooms from table2.
In common language (a good approach for constructing SQL queries) you would say:
Grab the person(s) from table1 who have passed from all the rows of table2:

Take a look at here:
[Fetching only rows that match all entries in a joined table (SQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333750/fetching-only-rows-that-match-all-entries-in-a-joined-table-sql)

But as Jamie said this is not a proper sql syntax and way of thinking